# how can i instantiate an instance of an ocx at runtime in vb6 code?

Tags: vb6, ocx

how can i instantiate an instance of an ocx at runtime in vb6 code?

new keyword doesn't seem to work...

> Invalid use of New keyword

```
Set bob = new bobocxlib.bobcontrol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add it to your container's `Controls` collection e.g. adding an intrinsic textbox control to a VB form upon load:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim txt As TextBox
  Set txt = Me.Controls.Add("VB.TextBox", "MyTextBox")
  With txt
    .Move 120, 120, 2000, 285
    .Visible = True
  End With
End Sub
```

The control's name is the concatenation of library name as shown in the Object Browser (`VB`) and class name (`TextBox`).

Comment: +1 You can read more about this in Microsoft's KnowledgeBase article [How To Dynamically Add Controls to a Form with Visual Basic 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190670)

Comment: ok but the problem i was having was because I had component reference in the project and not a "reference". you can't have both apparently. i removed the toolbar style component reference in favour of a plain dll style reference and then it started working.